# What is the Razor Code for Experience Manager enabling a link in Tridion 2011?

Tags: experience-manager, siteedit

I have a link in my Razor template in one of these forms:

```
<a href="@item.link" target="_blank">@item.link_title</a>

<a href="@item.tridion_pdf" target="_blank">@item.link_title</a>
```

So the link & title are coming from content.  item.link is just a text field to an external URL & tridion_pdf is a link to a PDF stored in Tridion.  I want the user to be able to edit the link & title in Experience Manager (XPM).  Is this possible?  I've Experience Manager enabled images & text fields individually but not any quite like this where the fields I want to edit are within the same HTML tag structure

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I think I need a clarification.  This question is specifically about rendering the appropriate markup needed to enable fields for use in XPM.  If, for example, I just had a simple text field in a div, I could use the following:

```
<div>@RenderComponentField("title", 0)</div>
```

That generates markup like the following, which is fine for that field.

```
<span><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:99-9999", "ComponentModified" : "2013-05-09T13:06:27", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:99-99999-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2013-05-06T13:48:54", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false } -->
    <span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]"} -->
        Sample Title
    </span>
</span>
```

But if you look at my sample Razor-encoded links, I have 2 fields I want to edit, not just one.   So what do I do here?

```
<a href="@item.link" target="_blank">@item.link_title</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This doesn't so much seem to me, now, as a Razor question as it would be an Experience Manager question. The way that you grab the field and output it to HTML won't be any different - but your question isn't really about outputting content from a field. It's that, within experience manager, you want two fields to be editable rather than one - and one of those fields is an attribute on an HTML element while the other is visible text. Is that an accurate summary of the question?

Comment: Yes, that is my question.  I want to edit 2 fields that are in the same HTML Element.   One is text, the other is an attribute.  Want I to do is allow the users to edit the links.   Possible? Or Not?

Answer (score 4):

is `@item` a field in your component?

Also, is this a TBB that's being executed in a CT for a component?

Typically, if you're trying to access fields in a component, you want to tell that to razor by using `@Fields`

```
@Fields.link
```

You can also be more explicit by designating the the object:

```
@Component.Fields.link
```

Therefore, I'd *think* that this is what you want:

```
<a href="@Fields.tridion_pdf" target="_blank">@Fields.link_title</a>
```

I haven't used Razor in Experience Manager, but this is how I use Razor for good ol' fashioned page templates and component templates.